# I am going to write file (logs) on server in deferent languages. english_name.txt is ok, "عاتبوها.txt" is showing "?????.txt" on server

Tags: java, tigase

Going to log on server in differant languages say "عاتبوها.txt" but it is showing "?????.txt" on server.

Code to write logfile on sever below :

```
BufferedWriter bw = null;
FileWriter fw = null;
String label = "label test";

// this content comming dynamic value from another method.
String content = "هذا هو اختبار عينة يرجى اختبار"; 
// this content comming dynamic value from another method.
String room    = "اختبار"; 


Date date = new Date();
         try {
                String dt = sdf.format(date);
                //String convertedRoom = new String(room.getBytes("UTF-8"));
                String fileName = room.concat("_").concat(dt).concat(".txt");
                File f = new File(fileName);
                if(!f.exists()) {
                    f.createNewFile();
                    f.setWritable(true);
                }
                fw = new FileWriter(fileName,true);
                bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

                bw.write(content);

                bw.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (bw != null)
                        bw.close();
                    if (fw != null)
                        fw.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    //ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Now the Log generating is ok on server and data on log file is also ok in a file... but the problem is fileName is not generate in another language like arebic.txt, its shown ??????????_.txt... please help.

Comment: What do you think `String convertedRoom = new String(room.getBytes("UTF-8"));` does? Remove that, it's unnecessary and potentially harmful.

Comment: try to use utf-8 for arebic languages.

Comment: Well that's completely wrong. Take it out. How did you come up with an idea like that, it doesn't work.

Comment: ok, try your solution and doing that.

Comment: It wasn't a solution. It was a comment about your code being completely wrong and you don't seem to understand at all what you're doing.

Comment: I am writing a file on server to view different language file for our support team to help people .... by checking logs... thats why i have did that... i am understanding what i am doing ... i am getting problem thats why i ask..

Comment: No, you understand what you *need to do*. What you don't understand is what you're doing. Your code is horrible. You call `sdf.format(date).toString();` even though `format()` already returns a `String`. You seem to also call `toString()` in a lot of other places where it's not needed... Is this homework?

Comment: have got date format from anywhere else... but i understand your points ... thanks...! .... then how we write a file on server in different language... file name should be in arebic.txt in my case it shown ???????.txt.

Comment: You just write it normally. There's nothing special required. The whole part with your `File f` can also be removed. It's completely unneeded and useless.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154873/discussion-between-mithilesh-kumar-and-kayaman).

Answer (score 0):

First a minor issue the java source must be edited in the same encoding (charset) as the java compiler compiles, in order to correctly translate Arabic text in the java source.
This can be tested by comparing a string literal in Arabic with a string literal with u-escaped Arabic: `"\u....\u...."`.

Here there are two problems: the file name and the file contents.
For the file name check the afore mentioned minor issue. If that does not help, you probably need to run the application server in a UTF-8 **locale**; look into Linux help.

Under Windows the filename indeed does not work at my place. You could write a **zip** file with latin characters, and have UTF-8 filenames in it.

The file contents must be written using a conversion so the resulting bytes are in UTF-8 (or for Arabic Windows-1256). Here FileWriter/FileReader are unusable, as they use the default encoding and one cannot specify the encoding as with other classes.

```
    String room = "اختبار";
    System.out.println("room = " + uescape(room));
    room =  "\u0627\u062e\u062a\u0628\u0627\u0631";

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date date = new Date();
    String dt = sdf.format(date);
    String fileName = room + "_" + dt + ".txt";
    Path f = Paths.get(fileName);
    try (BufferedWriter bw = Files.newBufferedWriter(f, StandardCharsets.UTF_8,
                StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.APPEND)) {

        bw.write("\r\n=s=" + label + "====" + date.toString() + "====>");
        bw.write(content);
        bw.write("=e=" + date.toString() + "===>\r\n");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // FIXME Do something with the exception...
    }
}

private static String uescape(String room) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append('\"');
    for (char ch : room.toCharArray()) {
        if (32 <= ch && ch < 127) {
            sb.append(ch);
        } else {
            sb.append(String.format("\\u%04x", 0xFFFF & ch));
        }
    }
    sb.append('\"');
    return sb.toString();
}
```

---

By the way, if the text is for Windows, use `\r\n` (CR-LF) instead of `\n` (LF).

Comment: cannot find symbol

[ERROR] symbol:   class Path    cannot find symbol

[ERROR] symbol:   variable StandardCharsets   cannot find symbol

[ERROR] symbol:   variable StandardOpenOption : please help

Comment: need to import class

Comment: Your IDE has some "fix imports" action; `import java.nio.file.Path;` and so on.

Comment: ya added import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

Comment: Have tested this code and run on server thats not creating file on server :(

Comment: That probably is because the filename cannot be created. (Assuming you know in which directory an "xyz.txt" would be created. Pick a latin file name. Or create an Arabic file by hand, and look how java scans its directory. Maybe that allows to copy the file and refill it.

Comment: I need to create file dynamically... with arabic_name.txt

Comment: It works with me, with u-escaped, but also plain Arabic. Only System.out prints question marks (as the system encoding is not for Arabic). Try `System.out.println("f: " + f.toAbsolutePath());` to see where the file would appear. Also it might be a rights issue. Try writing a regular file.